# Checkout endpoint for Alpha Bank in ASP.NET Core App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating an application in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I need to create a Checkout endpoint provided from a Greek bank. (Alpha Bank)
They have provided the necessairy implementation in an ASP.NET Web Forms app and I have to post the necessairy information to their endpoint.
The thing is that I am recreating the same exact form POST in my ASP.NET Core application and I can't get it to work.

**ASP.NET Web Forms implementation (working correctly)**

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id='form_digest' runat="server" >
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Height="45px" Style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px;
        border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-bottom-style: none"
        Text="Alpha Test Shop" Width="306px"></asp:Label><br />
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                MerchantID</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="mid" runat="server" Width="124px">123</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Order ID</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="orderid" runat="server" Width="138px">123</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Order Desc</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="orderDesc" runat="server" Width="153px">OrderDesc</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Ποσό</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="orderAmount" runat="server" Width="129px">0,2</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Νόμισμα</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="currency" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>EUR</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Τρόπος Πληρωμής</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="payMethod" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="">No pre Selection</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="visa">VISA</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="visaElectron">Visa Electron</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="mastercard">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="maestro">Maestro</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Σελίδα Confirmation</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="confirmUrl" runat="server" Width="247px">success.aspx</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Σελίδα
                Cancel</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="cancelUrl" runat="server" Width="247px">fail.aspx</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 198px">
                Digest</td>
            <td style="width: 330px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="digest" runat="server" Width="247px">raJKiCtB1Eupp/YmSKlAlWd+kT0=</asp:TextBox></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="113px" /><br />
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;
    </div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
    function noPostBack()
    {
        document.forms[0].action = "https://alpha.test.modirum.com/vpos/shophandlermpi";
        document.forms[0].__VIEWSTATE.name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
        document.forms[0].submit();

    }
```

**ASP.NET Core implementation (not working)**
**Form**

```
<form method="post" id='form_digest'>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="mid" name="mid" value="123" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="orderid" name="orderid" value="123" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="orderDesc" name="orderDesc" value="OrderDesc" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="orderAmount" name="orderAmount" value="0,2" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="currency" name="currency" value="EUR" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="payMethod" name="payMethod" value="visa"  class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="confirmUrl" name="confirmUrl" value="success.aspx" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="cancelurl" name="cancelurl" value="fail.aspx" class="form-control" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="row margin-top-10">
            <input id="digest" name="digest" value="raJKiCtB1Eupp/YmSKlAlWd+kT0=" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="row">
    <button id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-block u-btn-primary" onclick="noPostBack()"><span class="fa fa-money"></span> @localizer["AcceptAndPay"]</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
    function noPostBack() {
        document.forms[0].action = "https://alpha.test.modirum.com/vpos/shophandlermpi";
        //document.forms[0].__VIEWSTATE.name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

**Questions**
As you can see the form is the same. It is posted in the same endpoint however from the ASP.NET Core app I get an error

> "Invalid merchant id: null"

The only difference that I can see is in the script which I can't find what it is doing so it might have something to do with my error.

```
document.forms[0].__VIEWSTATE.name = 'NOVIEWSTATE';
```

On the other hand I was thinking maybe I am missing a configuration option but I can't find what.

I have been struggling with this for days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**PS**: I am giving an over-simplified example where I set the success url and cancel url as the same .aspx pages of the ASP.NET Web Forms example. This is just to recreate exactly the same digest value which is created from a function so don't bother about that.

**Update**
I tried to see my POST request through the HTTP Header Live plugin of Firefox and I saw that I don't POST my form values

Correct POST from WebForms app
[image]

Wrong POST from my app
[image]

So my question is why is this happening and what should I change?

Comment: If you aren't already using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I suggest you use it to debug your POST issue.  That way you can easily compare the requests and determine what the differences are.

Comment: @MarkG I added the POST request payload and indeed there is something weird that I don't understand happening. If you would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one form on the page? If so you may need to reference form by name instead of index, i.e. `document.forms["form_digest"].submit();`.  It's worth noting that none of your tags are particularly relevant to this question as it's a client side issue not server side.